# Probability: Binomial Distribution Problem w R code

Tags: probability, statistics

I am in an intro to probability class and I have absolutely no idea how to attempt this. Is this a binomial distribution? Even if it, I don't know how to start. I feel so, so clueless. O:

Burrowing owls sometimes build their nests in holes that were dug by prairie dogs, coyotes, or badgers and have been since abandoned. They sometimes line the nests with cattle or horse dung. Why? Perhaps it insulates the nest from temperature extremes. A possibility suggested by biologist Dennis Martin is that the owls use the dung to keep predators away. To test this theory, biologist Gregory Green observed lined and unlined owl nests in the Columbia River basin. He recorded whether the nest was raided or not in both samples.  For now consider only the lined nests. Green identified n=25 nests lined with dung and observed that only 2 were raided.

(a) If the probability that a nest is raided is 0.6, is Green's finding something that would  have much chance of happening? What would be that chance?
Explain and show work.  Also, provide the R code that you would use to find that chance using R.

(b) What should Green do to get a more accurate picture of how often lining the nest with dung prevents raiding by predators? Explain and justify your answer with some of the concepts learned this quarter.

Any kind of guidance would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A Google search of the phrase "R binomial distribution" would help for coding. Otherwise, consult your notes on identifying such distributions.

Comment: This seems to be partly, if not mostly, a question about R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=25,\, p=0.6)$ and you seek $P(X \le 2).$

In R statistical software the CDF of a binomial distribution is denoted by
the function `pbinom` where the second and third parameters are used to specify $n$ and
$p,$ respectively. So the answer using R is as follows:

```
pbinom(2, 25, .6)
[1] 8.033296e-08
```

Alternatively, one might use the PDF `dbinom` to sum the three relevant terms
$P(X = i),$ for $i = 0, 1, 2,$ as follows:

```
sum(dbinom(0:2, 25, .6))
[1] 8.033296e-08
```

Either way, it seems unlikely that lined nests have probability $p = 0.6$ of being raided.

---

To get a more accurate picture the investigator might look at more
lined nests and make a 95% confidence interval for $p$. For large
enough $n$ one could estimate $p$ as $\hat p = (X+2)/(n+4)$ and use the
'Agresti' 95% confidence interval

$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{n\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n+4}},$$

which is based on the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.

Lacking any of the context of your course, I have no idea whether this one suggestion,
among many possible ones, is an acceptable answer to part (b).